# Render image output disappeared with White screen

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, render-layers

In cycles render mode all objects are clearly rendered, but in the inal render image, objects disappear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. This sounds very much like you unticked "visible in render" for all
   of your objects in the scene (the camera symbol in outliner). While
   the rendered-view style in blender shows all Objects that have
   "visible in view" ticked in the outliner. So there can be
   discrepancies between visibility in render and the visibility in the
   rendered view.
2. Maybe you are rendering on a wrong layer? Or you have wrong layer settings... For example make sure you have all layers with your objects activated on the renderlayer: [image]
3. Maybe your main camera is not what you think and it is located somewhere where there really is nothing to see

(If this doesn't solve your problem provide some more info or a blend file, as there might be other problems with the same symptoms.)

Happy Blending! :)

Comment: thank you so much :) https://mega.nz/#!SCxg2AxS!2NwxwSGwRwLfpZg0i1Z-Qub-s4INg0-58Did1lqNGOU -> here i attached my blender file and find the problem .thanks

Comment: Thats an awesome scene you have there! :)   I included the solution to my answer. You have to activate the layers you want to render on your renderlayer (see picture)